# How do I turn one row in a Pandas dataframe into multiple rows based on a numeric column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to multiply the number of rows in my Dataframe output based on the value of a column (NumRealVisits).

(E.g. If NumRealVisits is 23, I want to duplicate that row 23 times.)

When I try the following code within a for loop:

```
s = df_content.set_index(['NumRealVisits']).stack()
df_content= (s.loc[s.index.repeat(s)].reset_index().drop(0, axis=1))
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Below is an example of what I have now and what I would like to achieve.

In:

```
ContentId   OrgId   Type    NumRealVisits   TotalTime
4063        6767    Topic   2               27
4062        6767    Topic   1               57
4061        6767    Topic   2               41
4004        6764    Topic   2               24
```

Out:

```
ContentId   OrgId   Type    NumRealVisits   TotalTime
4063        6767    Topic   2               27
4063        6767    Topic   2               27
4062        6767    Topic   1               57
4061        6767    Topic   2               41
4061        6767    Topic   2               41
4004        6764    Topic   2               24
4004        6764    Topic   2               24
```

Any help appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: @bharatk thanks, wasnt able to find the link to dupe

Comment: check the last answer in dupe

Comment: Perfect, thank you, that's just what I was looking for